# how to change Data Factory in Microsoft Integration Runtime COnfiguration Manager?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have Installed Microsoft Integration Runtime configuration Manager When I have Migrated Data from On-Premise SQL Server to Azure Data Lake and when I'm trying to use for another Azure Data Factory I don't find a space to add new key for the data factory. How to do it.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 22):

On the machine where your Integration Runtime is installed, you should have a file named:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\3.0\PowerShellScript\RegisterIntegrationRuntime.ps1`

Running it with your `domain\username` as your `$credential` and your `Key1` from ADF as your `$gatewayKey` will result in a re-registration, binding your local IR process to the IR identity in your new Data Factory.

Source: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7956

Comment: This worked, thank you. The service has to be running, and the script needs to be run with administrative privileges.

Comment: Saved my day!!! .\RegisterIntegrationRuntime.ps1 - gatewayKey <Key rom new IR> was sufficient. I was logged in with admin account and did have service running.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on Casper Lehmann's post, but I wanted to say that I tried running the script on PowerShell core (version 7.2.4) and it didn't work; however, in regular PowerShell (included in Windows) it works. Just FYI.

Comment: The Powershell default is to not let you run scripts at all. First, run Powershell with Admin privileges. Then run Get-ExecutionPolicy. It will probably show "Restricted". Next get help with Set-ExecutionPolicy to see the types of policies. If you choose "Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned" you will have to sign your scripts. Values for Set-ExecutionPolicy are: Restricted, AllSigned, RemoteSigned, Unrestricted.

Answer (score -3):

You can reuse an existing self-hosted integration runtime infrastructure that you already set up in a data factory. This enables you to create a linked self-hosted integration runtime in a different data factory by referencing an existing self-hosted IR (shared).

To share a self-hosted integration runtime by using PowerShell, see [Create a shared self-hosted integration runtime in Azure Data Factory with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-shared-self-hosted-integration-runtime-powershell).

For a twelve-minute introduction and demonstration of this feature, watch the following video: [Hybrid data movement across multiple Azure Data Factories](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1bCkENsaLY).

For more details, refer "[Sharing the self-hosted integration runtime with multiple data factories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#sharing-the-self-hosted-integration-runtime-with-multiple-data-factories)".